# Multiple-choice conditional rendering by enum constant

Tags: vue.js, enums, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I am *extremely* new to Vue.js, so excuse the basic question.

What is the simplest (and/or recommended, and/or [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)-compliant) way to display a text label based on a value using Vue, that I know will be only one of a limited set of values (e.g., an enum constant from the Java business logic)? My Java enum currently has the following definitions (obviously Vue does not depend on Java, except that my project is structured that way, and these constants eventually get converted to JSON string values when sent to the Vue view):

```java
public enum Color { BLACK, RED }
```

I have messages set up in a .js file as follows:

```js
export default {
en: {
    color: {
        red: 'Red',
        black: 'Black'
    },
...
```

and in the view template I currently use the following:

```xml
...
<td>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex>
      <div v-if="props.car.paint === 'RED'">{{ $t('color.red') }}</div>
      <div v-else>{{ $t('color.black') }}</div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</td>
...
```

But is this the recommended way? Mr. Ford has now already relented and allowed a color choice of red for his cars, not only the default black - but if market pressures cause another color(s) to be added to the choices, both the messages file as well as the view template file will have to be updated. **Can this be done so that only an add of the new text string to the messages file would be needed in future (and not both files)?** How?

Comment: I don't see why this can't be done.

Comment: @YomS. obviously it can be done, I'm basically interested in a way to limit the changes to as few as possible places (due to (1) laziness and to (2) lower the chance of errors being introduced with changes - the basic thinking behind the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

Comment: How about setting up an API endpoint that returns these messages and parsing them on any pre-`mounted` lifecycle hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With thanks to Phil for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57085780/2114313) - I have decided to not use it, but his "Possible improvements" did show me some more considerations that I wanted to take into account.

I eventually decided to provide a simple translation method (could be expanded, depending on how much improvements are required). This moves the logic to the JS code while being reasonably succinct.

View template:

```xml
...
<td>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex>
      <div>{{ colorText(props.car.paint) }}</div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</td>
...
```

JS:

```js
export default {
    ...
    methods: {
        colorText(color) {
            switch (color) {
                case 'RED':
                    return $t('color.red');
                case 'BLACK':
                default:
                    return $t('color.black');
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do the following:

```js
export default {
en: {
    color: {
        RED: 'Red',
        BLACK: 'Black'
    },
...
```

```xml
...
<td>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex>
      <div>{{ $t(`color.${props.car.paint}`) }}</div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</td>
...
```

Possible improvements:

- Add some validation that the color exists
- If you don't like that the translation keys are CAPS, you could use a dictionary that maps from the color in CAPS to the translation key.